ARM SWD Programming Problems
I am trying to erase a NRF52840 and the erasing fails. This is the relevant schematics:

Notice that SWDIO is tied to the unused P1.01 for ease of placement and routing. Similarly SWDCLK is tied to P1.04.
The programmer is setup to provide clock at 10KHz.
This is a frame from the oscilloscope:

The green trace if VTRef/VCC which is stable at approx. 3.3V.
The blue trace is the SWDIO which seems largely OK.
The yellow trace is the clock which has missing cycles and from what I understand about the SWD protocol, it is not supposed to be like that.
Notice that this problem is intermittent.
There is no offending circuitry that could cause the erratic behavior. An issue could be impedance/attach problems as the IC is on flex.
I am using Segger and J-Flash. The output is a time-out error, so it is probably checksum problem when reading registers. Sometimes, I manage to erase/read/program but in most cases I get timeout/the described intermittent behavior.
Any thoughts and comments on helping me analyze the situation would be highly appreciated!

What output / errors do you get from your tools? What tools are you using? (software and hardware)

I am using Segger and J-Flash. The output is a time-out error, so it is probably checksum problem when reading registers. Sometimes, I manage to erase/read/program but in most cases I get timeout/the described intermittent behavior.

Please add these details to your question, using the edit button.

I have done this, thanks!

@major4x Why would the clock have no pauses? If there is nothing to transfer, why run the clock? Pauses are allowed.

@Justme: You are right, I was only wondering why the I/O would be asserted one during some non-communication time. Anyhow, we're investigating some very low-level problem, like bad impedance or capacitance or open circuit or something in the Nordic pulling up or down on the signal or distorted clock or ...
